# Fill Empty Cells in Excel Based on Signature

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have, in an excel document the following table:

AAA | BB

AAA | blank

AAA | BB

ABA | AB

ABA | blank

is there a way to fill the blank cells in column 2 with a value from another row in column 2 if there is a match between the values of column 1?

That is, I'd like to have:

AAA | BB

AAA | BB

AAA | BB

ABA | AB

ABA | AB

And please assume the order may not be as nice as in the example.

Comment: If the target cells (second column) is to receive data somehow, then the only ways are: (1) set in a third column a formula that renders a value ONLY of the cell in the second column is empty, or (2) A small VBA macro. [Note: for the first option, you may need to use the VLOOPUP function].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an array formula in a third column with INDEX & MATCH

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$5=A1)*(LEN($B$1:$B$5)>0),0))
```

Array formula must be entered by using Ctrl-Shift-Enter and Excel will automatically insert the curly braces.

[image]